# Insert Hyperlinks in Custom Content Editor Web part SP 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

I have a weird situation in content editor web part. entered text and made it as hyperlink - then went into second line to enter text and text still follows the hyperlink which was applied on the first line but i want that to be a plain text. I have selected the second line to remove hyperlink but in ribbon LINK option itself is greyed out.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I would edit the Content Editor WP in HTML view mode, as the ribbon controls are not always helpful and you get more flexibility with the HTML view.

For you links in the HTML view, just add:

```
<a href="url">Link</a>
```

Comment: Actually we cannot ask the content authors to go into HTML and change it. is there any jQUERY, CSS fix for this? Thanks